# Can't get pushes list while passing “searchCriteria.refName=master” parameter in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Here is my code snippet:

```php
/*
 * Get Pushes List Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
 */
function getPushesList(){
    global $baseUri;
    global $organization;
    global $project;
    global $repositoryId;
    global $branch;
    global $username;
    global $accessToken;
    $url = $baseUri . '/' . $organization . '/' . $project . '/_apis/git/repositories/' . $repositoryId . '/pushes?api-version=5.1';
    $queryArr = [
        'searchCriteria.refName' => $branch,
        'searchCriteria.includeRefUpdates' => 'false',
        '$top' => 1,
    ];
    $queryStr = http_build_query($queryArr);
    $authorization = 'basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $accessToken);
    $url .= '&' . urldecode($queryStr);
    //$url sample: https://dev.azure.com/kmx3ecup/img_bed/_apis/git/repositories/img_bed/pushes?api-version=5.1&searchCriteria.refName=&searchCriteria.includeRefUpdates=false&$top=1
    // echo $url;exit;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'authorization: ' . $authorization
        ],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    ];
    //In case you need a proxy
    // $options[CURLOPT_PROXY] = 'http://127.0.0.1:1087';
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $retArr = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retArr;
}

$baseUri = 'https://dev.azure.com';

$organization = '<YOUR_ORGANIZATION>';
$project = '<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>';
$repositoryId = '<YOUR_REPOSITORY_ID_OR_REPOSITORY_NAME>';
$branch = '';
//Question: if I set $branch to "master", then it returns: {"count":0,"value":[]}, but actually master branch have many files.
//DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
//$branch = 'master';
$username = '<YOUR_USERNAME>';
$accessToken = '<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>';
$reponseJson = getPushesList();
echo $reponseJson;
```

Question: If I set `$branch` to "master",it returns: {"count":0,"value":[]}, but actually master branch have many files, and if I set `$branch` to empty string, it returns normal result,  but, I have only one branch, that is `master` branch, I mean if I set branch to empty string, it's still getting files from the default branch(`master` branch) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use parameter `searchCriteria.refName` to query the master branch, you should set `$branch` to `refs/heads/master` which is the ref name for master branch.

If you set $branch to empty string, the result is not from the default barnch. You will get the pushes lists ordered by push id in the repo's level. 
In your case, it will return the lists of master branch, since you only have one branch.

Comment: Turn out that I should set `$branch` to `refs/heads/master` rather than `master`, it works, thank you so much.